# Reactjs : give text input to select element(combo box)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a react js select element. I am giving a set of options to that element such that the user can select. In addition to that I need to add a place holder to that element and make it able to type values and enter as in a text box. Then the users can either enter custom values to it or select an element from the drop down.

Below is the code snippet I used for implementing the select element. But it only allows selecting. Can anyone help me to implement a select element which allows inputting text and place holder.

```
<select className="form-control form-control-sm" ref="LayerL6Select" name="LayerL6Select"  id="LayerL6Select">
<option value="1">Apple</option>    
<option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `<input>` followed by [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).Here is example in html you can convert in into react.
Note that `id` attribute of `<datalist>` should be added `list` attribute of the `<input>`

According to [DOCS](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element)

> The `datalist` element is hooked up to an `input` element using the `list` attribute on the input element

```html
<input placeholder="myplaceholder" list="opts"/>
<datalist id="opts">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did like that and the place holder works properly. The list is added to the combo box too. But the problem is I have click twice on the combo box to load the data. Can you help me to solve that issue and load the data list in once.

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for short time solution. I would suggest following react-select library which helps you to achieve what you want.

https://react-select.com/home

else if you ask this for your personal learning here its source code, you could learn from it source code.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select